# Magento 2 how to update price on quantity change in product detail page using knockout

Tags: magento2, price, knockoutjs, qty, magento231

I am using magento version 2.3.2

I want update price based on Qty change using Knockout js in Product detail page

anyone help here, thank in advance

Comment: anyone help here please

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet :(   
if you have got then please share it

Comment: Find any solution?